# How to access another file in GO

Tags: go, mux

I'm trying to access a controller from `main.go` but I'm getting the following error:

```
./main.go:34:28: cannot refer to unexported name controllers.getUserDetails
./main.go:34:28: undefined: controllers.getUserDetails
```

here's a snippet of my `main.go`, I've removed some extra code

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "os"
  "log"
  "github.com/urfave/negroni"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "github.com/joho/godotenv"
  "Go-Social/controllers"
 )

 func main() {
   router := mux.NewRouter()
   UserRouter := router.PathPrefix("/api/user").Subrouter()
   UserRouter.HandleFunc("", controllers.getUserDetails).Methods("GET")

   env := os.Getenv("GO_ENV")
   if "" == env {
    env = "Development"
   }

   // appending middlewares
   server := negroni.Classic()

   // router handler with negroni
   server.UseHandler(router)

   // starting server
   server.Run(":" + os.Getenv(env + "_PORT"))

 }
```

my `controller.go` file

```
package controllers

import (
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

func getUserDetails(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("here")
  message := "Hello World"
  w.Write([]byte(message))

}
```

Please Help I'm new to Go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert `func` name `getUserDetails` to `GetUserDetails` in `controller.go` will do the trick. Because the first letter of exported item from package should be an **UPPERCASE UNICODE**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to use a function from another package, you need to export it (`GetUserDetails`)

as said [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package

```
func GetUserDetails(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("here")
  message := "Hello World"
  w.Write([]byte(message))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the getUserDetails function is in another package it cannot be accessed. Only functions starting with capital letter can be accessed. That's how encapsulation works in Go.

```
func GetUserDetails(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("here")
  message := "Hello World"
  w.Write([]byte(message))
}
```

So in your main:

```
UserRouter.HandleFunc("", controllers.GetUserDetails).Methods("GET")
```

Language like Java, enCAPSulation in class-based OOP is achieved through private and public class variables / methods.
In Go, encapsulation is achieved on a package level.

In other words, in Go, starting with capital letter for any package object (type, variable or function) will allow you to access it from another package.