# I am trying to handle different versions in a api url call golang

Tags: api, http, go

```
   func New(url string) APIRequest {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("/api/%s%s", hmac.version, url)
    r := APIRequest{URL: url}
    return r
      }
```

whenever I use the
**    ***url := fmt.Sprintf("/api/%s%s", hmac.version, url)***
I get this error pkg\apirequest\apirequest.go:125:34: cannot refer to unexported name hmac.version
I am unsure as to what this means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the [basics in the Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/basics/3).

Comment: See similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24487943/13631587), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53369360/13631587),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking struct function gives "cannot refer to unexported field or method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487943/invoking-struct-function-gives-cannot-refer-to-unexported-field-or-method)